# How to get the tree hash of the index in git?

Tags: git

With git, how can I get the tree hash of the staged changes? That is, what the tree hash of the commit (not the commit hash) would be if I committed the changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to commit the tree:

```
git commit-tree
```

#### Explanation

You don't have to make a complete commit—though of course that will also work.  You just need the *snapshot* that the commit would have.

Fortunately, the way `git commit` works is that it builds the commit in several stages.  At one time, `git commit` was a simple shell script, that ran these other more-basic Git commands:<sup>1</sup>

1. `git write-tree`: this takes no arguments, and—if it succeeds—makes a tree object from whatever is in the index right now, and prints the hash ID to its standard output.
2. `git commit-tree`: this takes several parameters (as many parent hash IDs as you choose, and one tree hash ID) and a commit message, and builds a commit object.  The commit's snapshot is the tree whose hash ID you gave it, which comes from step 1.  The command prints the hash ID of the new commit object to its standard output.
3. `git update-ref`: this updates a reference, such as a branch name.  It takes at least two arguments: the name to update, and the new value (or a flag to indicate "delete the name").

All you want from this is step #1.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git update-ref` might be newer than the commit shell script, since in the bad old days, writing a ref just meant using an appropriate `echo` command.  The symbolic `HEAD` ref was just a symbolic link.  References were never packed.  Once references got fancier and needed locking, `git update-ref` became necessary.

Comment: Thanks :)! So it seems the answer here is to just use `git write-tree` since that gives the current state of the index as a tree hash. It's unfortunate that that also writes an object to the store but I guess garbage collection will clean that eventually if it doesn't end up getting used.

Comment: Yes. It also functions as a test: *can* the index be written out as it is? (If you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, it cannot.)